# Sampling an image

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D image G(m,n).

G is constructed by first acquiring k-space values and then inverse Fourier transforming.
The k-space consist m*n number of complex values.

What is meant by  acquiring only 1/q of this amount (from m*n)? (q is a positive number)

In a scheme I will keep only 1/q th of the original k-space values.
Other elements 0f the original k space will make to zero/one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Discarding a Fraction of Least Significant Frequency Components

One method is to use the `fft2()` function to convert the image to the frequency domain and delete the least significant frequency components based on their magnitudes. To find the least significant values the `sort()` function is used and the corresponding indices are returned. We can set the specific indices corresponding to the lowest frequency components to zero using matrix-indexing. You've pretty much described what has to be done above, but to provide more context:

• 1/`q` frequency components must remain.

• 1 - (1/`q`) frequency components must be set to zero/deleted.

---

[image: Frequency Sampling Image]

```
%Grabbing a built-in test image%
Image = imread("peppers.png");

%Converting to grayscale if colour%
if size(Image,3) == 3
   Image = rgb2gray(Image); 
end   
 
%Converting to frequency domain%
Frequency_Domain = fft2(Image);

%Sorting the the frequency domain values from greatest to least magnitude%
[Sorted_Coefficients,Sort_Indices] = sort(reshape(abs(Frequency_Domain),[numel(Frequency_Domain) 1]),'descend');

%Evaluating the number of coefficients to delete%
Number_Of_Coefficients = length(Sort_Indices);
q = 40;
Preserved_Fraction = 1/q;
Number_Of_Coefficients_To_Keep = round(Preserved_Fraction*Number_Of_Coefficients);

%Finding out which values to deleted based on the indices corresponding to the sorted array%
Delete_Indices = Sort_Indices(Number_Of_Coefficients_To_Keep+1:end);
Frequency_Domain(Delete_Indices) = 0;

%Evaluating how many frequency components were deleted%
Number_Of_Deleted_Frequency_Components = numel(Delete_Indices);
fprintf("Deleted %d frequency coefficients\n",Number_Of_Deleted_Frequency_Components);

%Converting the image back to the spatial domain%
G = uint8(ifft2(Frequency_Domain));
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Image);
title("Original Image");
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(G);
title("Frequency Sampled Image");

disp(1 - (numel(Delete_Indices)/numel(Frequency_Domain)));
```